# Get results that are between (inclusive) A and D

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to do a mysql query where I return results that start with (eg.) A-D, aka would return:
 - animal
 - bank
 - coke
 - dog
but not: igloo

Seems pretty simple but can't figure out an efficient way to do it.

I mean I can get it based on one letter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE 'A%'
```

but how could I do this with multiple letters easily. I considered a loop 'incrementing the letter from A to D but that doesn't make much sense with letters. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried a `REGEXP`?

Comment: `$letter = 'A'; while($letter != 'E') { echo $letter++; }` or `foreach(range('A','D') as $letter) { echo $letter; }` both make a great deal of sense; but using a regexp in your SQL is a better solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE word REGEXP '^[A-D]';
```

Comment: I don't think this can use any index which makes it slow for large data sets.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand that's true, the fastest option would propably be to add a column with only the first letter of the worlds in lowercase OR uppercase notation and fill it when inserting/updating records.

Comment: I think it can use an index - by virtue of the fact that it's accessing the start of the word.

Answer (score 3):

A normal [`between`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) works great and can use the index.

```
Select * from table where word between 'a' and 'e' and word != 'e';
```

All words starting with 'a' should be bigger than 'a' and all words starting with 'd' should be smaller than 'e'.

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c93c/1) to show that it conceptually works and also a compare against the regexp alternative. Check out the execution plan to see how the index is used.

Comment: Wow. Without any like operators?

Comment: this does not work as suggested, after a few manual tests it looks like it excludes entries which should be captured by the last character of the sequence (in this case the 'e')

Comment: 'e' is outside the range (a-d) so words starting with 'e' should not be included.